# C# Perforce P4 API: Client.GetSyncedFiles causes an exception

Tags: c#, perforce

I'm trying to view files in my workspace, eventually I want to use `GetSyncedFiles()` to simply view the current state of the files and what revision it is so I can alert the user. But I can't perform the most simple operation with no flags.

The message to the exception is `"GetSyncedFiles has no valid options\r\nParameter name: options"`.

I've tried omitting the file list and setting different flags in the options, always the same result.

```
try
{
    Perforce.P4.Server srv = new Perforce.P4.Server(new ServerAddress(PerforceServer + ":" + PerforcePort));
    Repository epo = new Perforce.P4.Repository(srv);
    repo.Connection.UserName = PerforceUser;
    repo.Connection.SetClient(PerforceWorkspace);
    repo.Connection.Client.Name = PerforceWorkspace;
    repo.Connection.Connect(new Perforce.P4.Options());
    repo.Connection.Login(PerforcePassword);

    List<FileSpec> fileSpecs = new List<FileSpec>();
    foreach (var filename in Directory.GetFiles(DirectoryWithTargetFiles))
    {
        fileSpecs.Add(new FileSpec(new ClientPath(filename)));
    }

    SyncFilesCmdOptions cmdFlags = new SyncFilesCmdOptions(SyncFilesCmdFlags.None);
    FileSpec[] fsa = fileSpecs.ToArray();
    var someFiles = m_repo.Connection.Client.GetSyncedFiles(cmdFlags, fsa);//execution gets to here
}
catch (Perforce.P4.P4Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
catch (Exception ee)
{
    //this exception will hit
    Console.WriteLine(ee.Message);
}
```

Comment: Seems like there is [another overload](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4api.net/p4api.net_reference/html/M_Perforce_P4_Client_GetSyncedFiles_1.htm) for `GetSyncedFiles()` that takes in a list and then the options. Does that also give the same result?

Comment: I haven't, it looks like it is asking for a list of abstract type, as though I've made a collection of objects inheriting from it, something which I don't have.

Comment: `IList<FileSpec>` is an interface and is compatible with `List<FileSpec>`, you can directly pass this list (`fileSpecs`) without converting it to an array as the first parameter and pass the options as the second parameter.

Comment: I just tried that, I got the same results :(

Comment: Is there an equivalent Perforce command for `GetSyncedFiles()`?

Comment: `FileSpec` has a property called `Version`. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the  [source code of the Perforce .NET API in the GitHub repository](https://github.com/perforce/p4api.net/blob/5ca6cee506c17d1ee11631a8cc69b86bd39f77b9/p4api.net/Client.cs):

```
public IList<FileSpec> GetSyncedFiles(Options options, params FileSpec[] files)
    {
        if (options != null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("GetSynchedFiles has no valid options", "options");
        }
        return runFileListCmd("have", options, files);
    }
```

It can be noticed that if the `options` is anything other than `null`, it throws an `ArgumentException`.
Hence, in order for this to work, you have to pass `null` for the options:

```
var someFiles = m_repo.Connection.Client.GetSyncedFiles(null, fsa);
```

Also, the second overload redirects it to the same method:

```
public IList<FileSpec> GetSyncedFiles(IList<FileSpec> toFiles, Options options)
    {
        return GetSyncedFiles(options, toFiles.ToArray<FileSpec>());
    }
```

Comment: That's crazy, I tried looking up the source on git but couldnt find it. I'd say this answer answers it without any doubt.

Comment: @coolmrcroc Yes, that is a really bad way to put it. I don't know much about the API and Perforce, but I'd rather not make the options as part of the method signature. Or at least, they should have also made it work with empty options. It could be that they plan to include valid options for this method in a future release.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that an empty option object is marked as invalid:

If you look at the documentation, the option has many many subclasses that override the default option class
https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4api.net/p4api.net_reference/html/T_Perforce_P4_Options.htm

Have you tried any of those options like [this one](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4api.net/p4api.net_reference/html/T_Perforce_P4_DescribeCmdOptions.htm)? Or have you tried just passing null? or omitting the line?

```
repo.Connection.Connect(new Perforce.P4.Options());
```

Comment: I've tried null for options of both Connect() and GetSyncedFiles(), I've also tried variants of options, to the same results. Maybe there is an option I need to set when using Connect() that further allows use of GetSyncedFiles(), or something in the Perforce software running on server that needs to be switched on?

Comment: No wait, I tried null for GetSyncedFiles() after using the other version of the function as suggested in a commend to my and that worked. It also worked as a preview, it made no changes. I suppose I just need to find the correct options to use.

Comment: I think so, I think you need to specify what you want to do with the files in the options